# Test keeps on failing even though function runs right

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm running a unit test using visual studio native unit test. The test keeps on failing even though the function works

test code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../banking/datamanagement.cpp"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace BankingTest
{
    TEST_CLASS(TestClass)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            
            datamanagement testob("testFile.json");
            bool testFileReturn = testob.loadfile();

            Assert::IsTrue(testFileReturn);
                    
        }
    };
}
```

Function:

```
bool datamanagement::loadfile() {

    jsonFile.open(this->filename);
    if (jsonFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File is loaded" << std::endl;
        
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Failed to open" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }


};
```

when I run the function outside the test it works just fine.

**I put in the absolute path for the file and it worked thank you!**

Comment: build in 'debug' configuration, set a breakpoint in the function, and select debug test instead of run test.  Step through the code and see what is happening.

Comment: Have you considered that your program's current working directory might not be the directory where this file is located?

Comment: @WalidZein are you sure this is C++ code, there seems to be a json file in there....

Comment: @YunfeiChen it just reads a json file

Comment: @paddy the test folder and the code are both in the same directory

Comment: Doesn't matter if the file is in the same directory as the code.  I'm talking about the _working directory_, which is the directory the operating system is using for resolving relative path names while your process is executing.  This is the directory from which the program was executed, _not necessarily_ where the executable resides.